# Can a Taiwanese enter Mexico based on a visa waiver from USA?

Tags: visas, esta, mexico, taiwanese-citizens

I'm British and my girlfriend is Taiwanese. We are currently in the US and have ESTAs (we applied through the US website).

I know what I need to do, but can my girlfriend (Taiwan passport) enter Mexico with the US ESTA?

Answer (score 3):

She [needs a visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Taiwanese_citizens). With a US visa she would not have done but VWP is not a visa.

> / 26JAN17 / 1825 UTC
>
> National Chinese Taipei (TW)    /Destination Mexico (MX)
>
> Mexico (MX)
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be   valid on arrival.
>   - Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or accepted departure document For details, click here is required by the US immigration authorities.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Passengers with an emergency or a temporary passport.  Admission and Transit Restrictions:
> - Passengers with a non-machine readable passport are not   allowed to enter or transit Mexico.
>
>   - This does not apply to passengers with an emergency or a    temporary passport.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a valid visa issued by
>   Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State For
>   details, click here for a maximum stay of 180 days.  Visa required,
>   except for Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card For details,
>   click here valid for travel to  MEX  if traveling on business, for a
>   maximum stay of 180 days. The card is valid for the countries listed
>   on the back of the card. Minors:
>   - Passport not required for alien minors (up to/incl.17 years   of age) registered in their parent/guardian passport,   provided
>   traveling with the passport holder. 
>   - All minors under 14 years of age, when traveling alone,   should be met by an adult.  Additional Information:
>
> - A valid Mexican visa in an expired passport is accepted if   the passenger also has a valid passport. Warning:
> - Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card must travel   with a passport. The passport number and nationality must match those stated on the card.
> - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.
>
> [Timaticweb](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=TW&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=MX&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) Version 1.3 26 January 2017

Comment: OK, but the main point was: why the entire section rather than the relevant part? Much less tiring to read

Answer (score 2):

[VisaHQ Passport and Visa Services site says this](https://mexico.visahq.com/requirements/taiwan/#!mexico-Tourist-visa):

> Citizens of Taiwan residing in Taiwan must apply for avisa to Mexico in person at the nearest consulate of Mexico in Taiwan. Please note, application procedures and fees may vary by location. If there is noconsulate of Mexico in Taiwan there may be a consulate of Mexico in a neighboring country that covers the jurisdiction of Taiwan.
>
> **While we cannot process your travel visa request, travelers should take note of the following advice:**
>
> - **Check the current validity of your passport**
>
> For international travel, all travelers will need a passport, valid for at least 90 days following your departure date. However, we strongly recommend traveling with six months validity on your passport at all times.
>
> It is also recommended that your valid passport have at least two un-used pages remaining, for any necessary entry and exit stamps that may be issued. It is also a good idea to review the number of pages and validity remaining your passport well in advance of overseas travel. This will allow for time needed if a replacement passport may be required.